# Pipe notation for more than two types in a type hint

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am trying:

```py
def foo(x: int | float | str):
    pass
foo(0)
```

and get the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'

Is it possible to use more than two types with pipe notation or I have to write `Union`?

Comment: @Swifty I saw it before posting, but it doesn't seem to deal with a union of more than two types...

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Swifty This shouldn't work without problem in python 3.9. PEP 604 wasn't added until 3.10.

Comment: Just curious to know why you cannot use the Union? This is the purpose of the Union technique to allow multiple data types in a neat and clean way

Comment: @erip Version 3.9.2. It works with two types `int | str`, but not with three.

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3.10 and it should work fine.

Comment: @arsho This is semantically the same as `typing.Union`; it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It does not work with two types in python 3.9.

Comment: @erip You are right. I forgot to run it and got mislead by PyLance recognizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactic sugar like this to represent union types wasn't added until 3.10 with the introduction of [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/). Update to 3.10+ or use `typing.Union`.